# How to access an object attribute from a String in Java?

Tags: java, class

I have a String that tells me what attribute I should use to make some filtering. How can I use this String to actually access the data in the object ?

I have a method that returns a List of strings telling me how to filter my List of objects. Such as:

`String[] { "id=123", "name=foo" }`

So my first idea was to split the String into 2 parts with:
`filterString.split("=")` and use the first part of the String (e.g. "id") to identify the attribute being filtered.

Coming for a JS background, I would do it like this:

```
const attr = filterString.split('=')[0]; // grabs the "id" part from the string "id=123", for example
const filteredValue = filterString.split('=')[1]; // grabs the "123" part from the string "id=123", for example
items.filter(el => el[`${attr}`] === filteredValue) // returns an array with the items where the id == "123"
```

How would I be able to do that with Java ?

Comment: Java is a strictly typed language, so the definition of an `item` is now relevant. In other words, please include the class you intend to use for the `items` list/array.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Check Serialization/Deserialization

Comment: That's very dynamic for Java. If the `el` variables in your JS snippet are `Map`s in Java, then it's feasible as `attr` would then be matched against the keys, but if `attr` is supposed to match the names of the properties of a class, I only see reflection to be used, which I generally don't recommend unless last resort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reflections to get fields of class by dynamic name.

```
@Test
void test() throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
    String[] filters = {"id=123", "name=foo"};

    List<Item> list = newArrayList(new Item(123, "abc"), new Item(2, "foo"), new Item(123, "foo"));

    Class<Item> itemClass = Item.class;

    for (String filter : filters) {
        String key = StringUtils.substringBefore(filter, "=");
        String value = StringUtils.substringAfter(filter, "=");

        Iterator<Item> iterator = list.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Item item = iterator.next();

            Field field = itemClass.getDeclaredField(key);
            field.setAccessible(true);
            Object itemValue = field.get(item);

            if (!value.equals(String.valueOf(itemValue))) {
                iterator.remove();
            }
        }
    }

    assertEquals(1, list.size());
}
```

But I agree with comment from sp00m - it's slow and potentially dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

This code should work :

```
  //create the filter map
  Map<String, String> expectedFieldValueMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (String currentDataValue : input) {
        String[] keyValue = currentDataValue.split("=");
        String expectedField = keyValue[0];
        String expectedValue = keyValue[1];
        expectedFieldValueMap.put(expectedField, expectedValue);
    }
```

Then iterate over input object list ( have used Employee class with id and name fields & prepared a test data list with few Employee objects called inputEmployeeList which is being iterated ) and see if all filters passes, using reflection, though slow, is one way:

```
for (Employee e : inputEmployeeList) {
            try {
                boolean filterPassed = true;
                for (String expectedField : expectedFieldValueMap.keySet()) {
                    String expectedValue = expectedFieldValueMap.get(expectedField);

                    Field fieldData = e.getClass().getDeclaredField(expectedField);
                    fieldData.setAccessible(true);
                    if (!expectedValue.equals(fieldData.get(e))) {
                        filterPassed = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (filterPassed) {
                    System.out.println(e + " object passed the filter");
                }

            } catch (Exception any) {
                any.printStackTrace();
                // handle
            }
        }
```

Comment: You're missing the third line of the example: How to access a member of an object by name (and filter an array by its value)?

Comment: OP's question is, if I understood correctly, what should replace your sysout line.